# task hub name must be specified in host.json when using slots

Tags: azure-functions, azure-deployment-slots

[image]

On adding a staging slot in my function app, I see the error:

> task hub name must be specified in host.json when using slots

I updated host.json as follows:

```
{
    "version": "2.0",
    "extensions": {
        "durableTask": {
        "hubName": "staging"
        }
    }
}
```

Should I specify 2 hub names - for production and staging slots?

How do I fix that?

Comment: How would I control which host.json belongs to which slot? I'd like to separate the durable task hub names

Answer (score 2):

> Task hubs can also be configured using app settings

Check documentation here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/durable/durable-functions-task-hubs?WT.mc_id=Portal-WebsitesExtension&tabs=csharp#task-hub-names

You'd configure the specific value in each slot's settings.

Go to the `Environment variables` blade for your Function App's Slot.

In the `App settings` tab, add a new variable named `TaskHubName` with  `Deployment slot setting` checked. Now you can set this variable to different values on each slot.

Comment: can you elaborate on what that setting is? The Microsoft documentation simply says `When using deployment slots, it's a best practice to configure the task hub name using app settings.` which is unhelpful. The name needs to be set correctly and so far I've tried hubName, HubName, and hubname... none of which work

Answer (score 1):

AzureFunctionsJobHost__extensions__durableTask__hubName = "YOURTASKHUBNAME"

You have to use this key/value pair in configuration